# Best database structure to store year with optional month and day?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, database, database-design

I need to store birthdates, but for some people I only know the year and not the month and day. For month/day I will only allow either null or both of them filled out. How should I structure my database?

Currently I have this:

```
birth_year (YEAR)
birth_month (INT)
birth_day (INT)
```

Where `birth_month` and `birth_day` are nullable, but is it better to go for something like:

```
birth_date (DATE)
has_month_and_day (TINYINT/BOOL)
```

And set month and day to "01-01" if `has_month_and_day` is false?

Or this:

```
birth_year (YEAR)
bith_date (DATE)
```

And go for `bith_date` with the full date if everything is filled out and `birth_year` if `birth_date` is null?

Other suggestions? I still need to be able to tell if month and day was filled out so I can't just use one date column and set month and date to "01-01".

I will also need to filter by year and sort by date if that matters for the decision.

Thanks!

Edit // I found this in the MySQL docs. What do you think?

> MySQL permits you to store dates where the day or month and day are
> zero in a DATE or DATETIME column. This is useful for applications
> that need to store birthdates for which you may not know the exact
> date. In this case, you simply store the date as '2009-00-00' or
> '2009-01-00'.

Answer (score 2):

I would store them separately. You can always query on them as a full date using `CONCAT` and `CAST 'mystring' as date` if needed.

Comment: Ok so three columns with year/int/int? Or maybe there is a month type too?

Comment: In SQL databases nulls were designed to represent exactly that: missing/unrecovered data. So, the last two properties should be nullable.

Comment: I would stick to null values. Those “0000-00-00 00:00:00” dates in older DBs are a pain to come across and change.